# How can I let R recognize my mosaic as a data frame so I can use the ggplot2 package in R

Tags: raster, netcdf, mosaic, data-frame, ggplot

I have various climate projections for different values such. I extracted the certain values I needed using the brick function. Afterwards I took the average using the mosaic function. I want to use this mosaic to plot maps but R doesn't recognize the new mosaic brick as a data frame or raster. How can I use the output of the mosaic? Or is there another way to average the raster bricks which I can use for the ggplot2 analysis?

Here you can see the essence of my code

```
#create bricks from net cdf files
Climateproj1 <- brick(fn1)
Climateproj2 <- brick(fn2)
Climateproj3 <- brick(fn3)
Climateproj4 <- brick(fn4)

mosaic <-mosaic (Climateproj1, Climateproj2 , Climateproj3, Climateproj4, fun=mean)

ggplot()+   
  geom_raster(data = mosaic, aes(x=Long, y=Lat, fill = precipitation))
```